# update attribute of specific products in woocommerce

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I need to change the value of all product attributes that have a specific attribute with a specific value.
for example, I have 10 phones with `Ram(attribute): 64 GiB (attribute value)` and 5 Phone with `Ram(attribute): 64 GB (attribute value)`.
I need to change all products with `Ram: 64 GiB` to `Ram: 64 GB`, So there will be no `64GiB` anymore, I tried the below code and https://stackoverflow.com/a/65690805/6934036.  but they  didn't work

```
$product_id = 14352; //some product id
$storage = get_the_terms($product_id, 'pa_internal-storage');
$newStorage = '64GB';
update_post_meta($product_id, 'pa_internal-storage', $newStorage);
```

Comment: [`get_the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) is a taxonomy function, ie, it'll fetch terms for a post in a taxonomy (eg tags, category, etc). [`update_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/) will update the post's metadata. **These are two different things.** The first thing you need to work out is, which one do you need to be using?

Comment: I think my goal is obvious but I don't know how to implement it, I don't know much about woocommerce functions.

Comment: `get_the_terms()` and `update_post_meta()` aren't WooCommerce functions, they're part of WordPress core. But what you're doing in your code sample is comparing apples to oranges. Terms are part of a taxonomy, like tags; post meta is a different thing. Both can be used to help describe a post, but they're not the same thing. The question is, should `pa_internal-storage` be a taxonomy term, or post metadata? Your code is trying to have it both ways, and that won't work.

Comment: @PatJ I'm trying to update a product attribute, I think I should deal with metadata, not terms, thanks for the response.